# How to vertically center p tags text in css

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am working on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g658rhvy/10/embedded/result) in which I want to vertically centered text in css.

The HTML code which I have used in order to built the fiddle is:

```
<div class="poster text-center pt-4">
   <div class="item">
      <img class="item_poster_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/lbDo4tM.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="poster_name_location">
      <p class="mb-0">posted by,<span style="color:#ff8b5a;">hello</span></p>
      <p class="poster_location">located in, <span style="color:#ff8b5a;">San Francisco, California</span></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I need to add in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g658rhvy/10/embedded/result) so that text comes at the center of an image.

I tried adding the following css code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
.poster_name_location
{
middle
}
```

Comment: Try "margin-top: 50%;" .. This will center the div starting from its very top .. So may be you want to make it like 45% if this div supposed to have a height of 10% for example.

Comment: You add `align-items: center;` to `poster`: http://jsfiddle.net/g658rhvy/19/ ... and you can remove the `justify-content` from `.poster_name_location`. Note, both those properties belong to the Flexbox container (the one with `display:flex`)

Comment: And also note, it is not enough to only have prefix for the `display` value, e.g. `-ms-flex` (and not `-ms-flexbox` btw), it needs to be on the rest of the flexbox properites as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using `flex-box` & `align-items: center`.

```css
.item_poster_image {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.poster {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.poster_name_location {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text-center {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="poster text-center pt-4">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="item_poster_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/lbDo4tM.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="poster_name_location">
    <p class="mb-0">posted by, <span style="color:#ff8b5a;">hello</span></p>
    <p class="poster_location">located in, <span style="color:#ff8b5a;">San Francisco, California</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx, updated the example